# how to store value in function in r?

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to make a function to remove outliers.

```
 removeoutlier<-
  function(data,datacolumn){


Q<-quantile(datacolumn, probs=c(0.1,0.9),  na.rm = FALSE)

iqr <- IQR(datacolumn)
up <-  Q[2]+1.5*iqr # Upper Range  
low<- Q[1]-1.5*iqr # Lower Range


nooutlier2<-iris[iris$Sepal.Width > (Q[1] - 1.5*iqr) & iris$Sepal.Width < (Q[2]+1.5*iqr),]

return(nooutlier2)
```

}

I'd like to store values. But function only displayed values and not store the values.
How would I store values returned by function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `return(list(irq=irq, up=up, low=low, nooutlier2=nooutlier2))`

Comment: Tried. But doesn't store the value.

Comment: `newList <- removeoutlier(...); irq <- newList$irq; ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it in the global environment:
assign(name, nooutlier2, envir = .GlobalEnv)

Comment: Where do I write this code? Inside of the function?

Comment: Yes it's another way of doing "<-" where you can specify the environment. Within the function an environment is created and this let you reach the Global env